# ImpersonateLoggedOnUser in windows

Tags: c, windows, active-directory, token

I'm trying to learn some windows operating system security internals. I come across functions [`LogonUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonusera) and [`ImpersonateLoggedOnUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-impersonateloggedonuser) and I became interested in how they they work. So, I wrote some code to impersonate a network user, using `LogonUser` to get token and then impersonate it for current program using `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` function:

```c
int main(int argc, char**argv)
{

    HANDLE handle = NULL;
    LogonUserA(argv[1], argv[2], argv[3], LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50, &handle);
    if (handle == NULL)
    {
        printf("LogonUserA failed with error code %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("LogonUserA success\n");
    
        if (ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(handle) == 0)
        {
            printf("ImpersonateLoggedOnUser failed with error code %d\n", GetLastError());
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("ImpersonateLoggedOnUser success\n");

            system("dir \\\\MY-DC\\C$ > file.txt");
            if (RevertToSelf() == 0)
            {
                printf("RevertToSelf failed with error code %d\n", GetLastError());
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("RevertToSelf success\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect `system("dir \\\\MY-DC\\C$ > file.txt");` to access domain controller (MY-DC) and list its `C` drive, but it doesn't. To run code I give an domain admin credentials as input (e.g: `.\main.exe admin home.local admin` (username:`admin`, domain:`home.local`, password:`admin`)) and nothing is written out in file.txt and I get `Access denied` error.

As far as I read microsoft documents, the `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` function is expected to change current thread token so I think the `system("dir \\\\MY-DC\\C$ > file.txt");` should work and list C drive.

I couldn't find anyhting more and I appreciate your help.